# "Snapping" sub-tables back into parent table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm making a library for a program with the ComputerCraft mod in Minecraft. The library is an archive library, which uses the table.serialize function in Lua to archive files. In each function, you can supply the folders (sub-tables) to use; e.g. `add_folder(table, "new_folder", "folder1", "another_folder")` adds `new_folder` to `another_folder` that is inside `folder1`. I have made a recursive function to get the table from a list of folders:

```
local function getFolder(table, ...) return getFolder(table[select(1, expand(arg))], expand(table.remove(table, 1))) end
```

This works well when I add the information, but the functions return a modified version of this sub-table, as shown in the `add_folder` function:

```
function add_folder(table, name, ...)
  local folders = getFolder(table["data"], expand(arg))
  folders[name] = {}
  return folders --Returns incomplete table
end
```

I would like to "snap" this sub-table back into the parent so that the above function will return the whole table. How can I get this sub-table back into the parent?

Note that I can not use libraries that use C modules, as the ComputerCraft implementation of Lua is just an interpreter, and not designed to use compiled modules. Otherwise, I would totally use TAR.